# Uso de lapsos de tiempo (TimeSpan) en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, date

Tengo un nodo de ODATA, el cual automáticamente arroja datos en formato Json.

Una de las propiedades en este objeto, contiene un lapso de tiempo [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), pues se genera utilizando **`TimeSpan`** (de .Net)

Por ejemplo, un lapso de 7 horas se serializa así:

> "PT7H"

Consumo esta API desde un cliente en AngularJs y necesito sumar y restar horas y minutos, y JavaScript no tiene un tipo de dato nativo para TimeSpan.

Ustedes que son ninjas de JavaScript ¿Cómo manejan este tipo de situaciones? Es decir, ¿Cómo convierto ese formato a un objeto "amigable" de JavaScript el cual yo pueda usar?

¿Cuál librería es la recomendada? ¿moment.js? ¿date.js?

Aquí unos intentos míos que dan lástima:

```
var resultado=JSON.parse(valorTS); //mismo valor
var resultado=Date(valorTS); //Invalid date
```

(Misma pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893265/how-to-deserialize-json-timespan-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) soporta lapsos de tiempo ISO 8601 (igual que TimeSpan de C#), los llama **durations**. Incluye las operaciones básicas: sumar y restar. Si restas fechas, obtienes durations, si sumas fechas y durations obtienes fechas, si sumas/restas durations obtienes durations, si sumas fechas... no puedes, igual que DateTime y TimeSpan de c#.

Si fuera tú no invertiría valioso tiempo en desarrollar algo que esta hecho y ademes esta bien hecho, como Moment.js -salvo que sea como aprendizaje-.

```js
// ahora mismo 
var ahora = moment();
// lapso de tiempo de 7 horas...
var timeSpan = moment.duration('PT7H');

// los sumamos... 7 horas en el futuro
alert(ahora.add(timeSpan).format());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eres un(a) genio, GRACIAS!!!!!

Comment: buenísimo, yo había dado por hecho, por la pregunta, que moment no tenía eso.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no aprovechar la situación para crear una librería?

Si lo que querés es poder sumar y restar estos valores ya sea entre ellos y con dates sólo necesitas dos funciones (suma y resta).

```
module.exports = TimeSpan;

function TimeSpan (text) {
  if (this instanceof TimeSpan) {
    // magia para parsear el string "PT7H"
    this.horas = horas;
  } else {
      return new TimeSpan(text);
  }
}

TimeSpan.prototype.add = function (timespan_or_date) {
  // magia para sumar timespans
}
```